# Best approach to do auto versioning of an elixir application phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am doing hot code upgrade using distillery for a phoenix application. I used this to create the version of the application.

```
  def project do
    {result, _exit_code} = System.cmd("git", ["rev-parse", "HEAD"])
    git_sha = String.slice(result, 0, 7)

    [app: :evercam_media,
     version: "1.0.1-a#{git_sha}",
     elixir: "~> 1.7",
     elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env),
     build_embedded: Mix.env == :prod,
     start_permanent: Mix.env == :prod,
     compilers: [:phoenix] ++ Mix.compilers,
     aliases: aliases(),
     deps: deps()]
  end
```

this creates versions but that version doesn't work with hot code upgrades and messes up the `relup` file. When I do versioning like 1.0.1, 1.0.2 and 1.0.3. then hot code deploys works fine. but Is there any way to make this thing dynamic?

I am deploying using distillery to a remote server.

Update:

I am using distillery for deployment but the auto versions are not working unless they are 1.0.1 or 1.0.2 or 1.0.3. I have tried the answer below. as well as `git describe --tags` as well. but distillery only uses 2 versions then each time using the past version to create new release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with `git_sha` is that it’s not ordered. The next version is assumed to have a number that is greater than the previous one by trivial alphanumeric sort. With `sha` that’s not the case.

You might use date for that purpose. E. g.

```rb
git log -1 --date=raw --format=%cd
#⇒ 1535467693 +0200 # seconds since epoch
```

Now let’s elixir it:

```rb
{epoch, _} = System.cmd("git", ~w|log -1 --date=raw --format=%cd|)
[sec, tz] =
  epoch
  |> String.split(~r/\s+/, trim: true)
  |> Enum.map(&String.to_integer/1)
#⇒ [1527769224, 200]
sec + tz * 36 # * 60 * 60 / 100
#⇒ 1527776424
```

The number above is always growing.

---

*Sidenote:* use inplace binary pattern match instead of `String.slice/3` whenever possible:

```rb
{<<git_sha::binary-size(8), _rest::binary>>, _exit_code} =
  System.cmd("git", ["rev-parse", "HEAD"])
#⇒ {"556c53987eb55c82ffb6925f9f56eae5de01c119\n", 0}
git_sha
#⇒ "556c5398"
```

Comment: So instead of doing `System.cmd("git", ["rev-parse", "HEAD"])`, I should use date, what you use for autoversions?

Comment: You might do whatever you want; the date is _constantly growing_ with time, unlike `sha`, so it’s applicable for your needs. Also you might use commit number, or whatever constantly growing.

Comment: Thank you are a life saver.

Comment: Was that `sec + tz * 36 # * 60 * 60 / 100` ?

Comment: Was that what ?

Comment: this line? `sec + tz * 36 # * 60 * 60 / 100` was that a # or was that not a hash?

Comment: This is a comment explaining how the math was done there.

Comment: Okay its only working when you wait for some time and then create a new release not instantly or with new commit!

Comment: Can you please tell how to use commit number? which may increasing? but this is not working. its working when you do release after sometime not instantly

Comment: Check `git` docs on how to retrieve the commit number. This is completely out of scope of the initial question which I had answered 2 hours ago. One never has two subsequent releases within one second.

Comment: Okay thanks actually version is changing but distillery not creating an upgrade

Comment: Can we just use `DateTime.to_unix(DateTime.utc_now())` instead of this all GH commit time things? it will also grow each time

Comment: In general we could, but got sha is more informative.

Comment: We actually deploying a branch with hot-upgrade. and after testing branch many times, We need to deploy master again. now that's branch's commit date is greater and master is on old date. This is breaking hot-upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the approach I use for an application that eventually get build as a versioned production RPM. When built against a clean tag, the version is the tab name. Otherwise, the version includes the short commit hash and the commit count since the last tag.

It also supports override the auto versioning by including a VERSION file in the project's root directory.

```
# mix.exs
defmodule MyApp.Mixfile do
  use Mix.Project
  @default_version "v1.0.0-default"

  def project do
    [
      app: :my_app,
      version: version(),
      elixir: "~> 1.6",
      # ...
    ]
  end

  # ...

  defp version do
    # Build the version number from Git.
    # It will be something like 1.0.0-beta1 when built against a tag, and
    # 1.0.0-beta1+18.ga9f2f1ee when built against something after a tag.
    with {:ok, string} <- get_version(),
         [_, version, commit] <- Regex.run(~r/(v[\d\.]+(?:\-[a-zA-Z]+\d*)?)(.*)/, String.trim(string)) do
      String.replace(version, ~r/^v/, "") <> (commit |> String.replace(~r/^-/, "+") |> String.replace("-", "."))
    else
      other ->
        IO.puts("Could not get version. error: #{other}")
        @default_version
    end
  end

  defp get_version do
    case File.read("VERSION") do
      {:error, _} ->
        case System.cmd("git", ["describe"]) do
          {string, 0} -> {:ok, string}
          {error, errno} -> {:error, "Could not get version. errno: #{inspect errno}, error: #{inspect error}"}
        end
      ok -> ok
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Your default version is failing here
`iex(1)> Version.parse("v1.0.0-default")  :error`

Comment: @JunaidFarooq works fine for me 
    iex(25)> string = "v1.0.0-default"
    "v1.0.0-default"
    iex(26)> [_, version, commit] = Regex.run(~r/(v[\d\.]+(?:\-[a-zA-Z]+\d*)?)(.*)/, String.trim(string))
    ["v1.0.0-default", "v1.0.0-default", ""]
    iex(27)> String.replace(version, ~r/^v/, "") <> (commit |> String.replace(~r/^-/, "+") |> String.replace("-", ".")) |> Version.parse()
    {:ok, #Version<1.0.0-default>}

Comment: Okay thanks the above logic which I accepted is clean and nice. and Also you always need to touch your mix.exs file before doing upgrade release.

Answer (score 1):

Whether all you need is to make delivery happy, you might use [delivery config](https://github.com/edeliver/edeliver/wiki/Auto-Versioning) for that purpose. Just put the following line in your `.deliver/config`:

```
AUTO_VERSION=commit-count+git-revision+branch-unless-master
```

Comment: I am not using Edeliver. Its only distillery, here it is getting the current version `set version: current_version(:app_name)` but it dont get the latest version on mix release --upgrade, I dont know why

Answer (score 0):

The solution which we used was

```
defmodule EvercamMedia.Mixfile do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [app: :evercam_media,
     version: "1.0.#{DateTime.to_unix(DateTime.utc_now())}",
     elixir: "~> 1.11.1",
     elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env),
     build_embedded: Mix.env == :prod,
```

this one and it works perfectly alright.

the solution, I had accepted that won't work with the hot upgrade when you deploy a branch and then master.

Also, the most important part while deploying with **Ansible** is to touch your `mix.exs` as well so it can compile and pick up a new version.

I have written an article about it [Hot Code Upgrade](https://medium.com/@junaid_16874/hot-upgrades-whaaaaaaaat-29bad102795e)